# SMTP error after renewing my certificate (SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed)

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp

I renewed my certificate and restart Apache. Good, I have the lock, the site is back in https!

But, when I try to send an email with the pluging Easy WP SMTP, I obtain this with the full log SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL (4):

```
Connection: opening to ssl://xxxxxxxxx:465, timeout=10, options=array ()
Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 5.
```

OpenSSL Error messages:

```
error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib
error:0B06F002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_file:system lib
error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib
error:0B06F002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_file:system lib
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable cryptoConnection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://xxxxxxxxx:465 (Unknown error)SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I tried everything in the wiki … nothing worked.

NOTE: my STMP configuration is good because when I used the unsecure option I can send an email. The option said : “Allows insecure and self-signed SSL certificates on SMTP server. It’s highly recommended to keep this option disabled.”

Here my configuration :
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wordpress.conf

```
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/my_site_com.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/my_site_com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/my_site_com.ca-bundle.crt
```

```
php -i | grep cafile
openssl.cafile => before I renew the certificate this value was empty, so it supposed to work with an empty value.
```

Well, my conclusion is there a copy of my old certificate into the server, but where. I tried to set the openssl.cafile into the php.ini file to the pem and also to the ca-bundle … nothing worked.

Comment: is the cert self signed, if so you might want to enable '“Allows insecure and self-signed SSL certificates on SMTP server. It’s highly recommended to keep this option disabled.”'. Failing that ensure the path to to cetrificate is correct in the SMTP client

Comment: Sending mail from some PHP code in your web server has nothing to do with the SSL configuration of the web server, so providing this config does not help. The errors shown regarding `X509_load_cert_file` that there are permission problems with the CA file phpmailer is supposed to use, so look there instead.

Comment: I tried chmod 777 and also with many user (chown) for my ca-bundle and the pem, but nothing worked. Can I show the file who given the permission denied?